# Typescript how to decrare property as a list of keys of a generic parameter T of its class?

Tags: generics, typescript-generics

```
class A<T> {
    fields: Array<???>;
}
```

I want fields to hold a list of properties of `T`.
I've tried `A<T, K extends keyof T>` but then I need to provide two parameters when inheriting in the subclass `B extends A<C, ???>`. I've tried to move that `type K extends/= keyof T` into the class body but that is not recognized by Typescript.

**Q:** What is correct type annotation for a list of parameters of type variable class was parametrized with?

PS `A` will never be instantiated directly, but instead will be inherited after (e.g. `class B extends A<C> ...` and then `fields` will be filled in in those subclasses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one solution:

```
type KeysOf<T1> = keyof T1;

class A<T2> {
    fields: Array<KeysOf<T2>>;
```

Please note, that those two T's are different, just my convention.
`KeysOf` is generic in type it's describing. That enables me to later on pass the T my class is parameterized with.

Please note, I had to declare that type alias outside class body, as Typescript refused to compile otherwise.

Please note `type` supports generics only from certain typescript language version, so that trick may not work in older versions.